# Solving logical expressions in Java with minimum iterations

Tags: java, performance, logical-operators, coding-efficiency, truthtable

I'm working on solving the logical expressions in Java comprising of *AND*, *OR*, and *NOT* operators.

The program has to output if the input was `TRUE` for any Boolean values of the variables included. I've done it successfully but it is not efficient enough.

My current solution goes like:

Make a truth table for each variable in the expression and evaluate row by row.

```
(p ∧ ¬q) ∨ (r ∧ s) ∨ (¬p ∨ u)
```

In the above example, I'll have to evaluate the whole expression with a truth table of variables `p q r s`.

Now, I'm thinking of implementing an alternate solution that goes like this:
Consider the example above.

We can notice that even by just solving the `p ∧ ¬q` part, all of the expression comes out to be `TRUE`. This saves us the hassle of 3 extra variables.

Now, my question is this. How to program this in JAVA? How do I even get to know if the input does have a pattern like above? Or is it just an expression that I have to evaluate for the whole Truth Table? Like the one below

```
(p ∨ ¬q) ∧ (r ∨ (s ∧ (¬p ∨ u)))
```

Comment: At best, maybe you could simplify the expression using [boolean algebra](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/boolean/bool_6.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a well known NP-complete problem, see [Boolean Satisfiability Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem).

This means there is no known polynomial time solution, but there are many >P solutions out there.

You will have to brute force it and short circuit where you can. (ex: if all operators are `or` and you find a `true` value you can stop computation)